# Using sequelize belongsTo and hasOne results in a Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In my `Conversation` model, I have:

```
    Conversation.hasOne(sequelize.import('./audio'), { constraints: false })
```

And in `Audio`, I have:

```
    Audio.belongsTo(sequelize.import('./conversation'))
```

To load these, from another file, I'm doing:

```
    fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}`).forEach((modelFile) => {
        if (path.extname(modelFile) === '.js' && modelFile !== 'index.js') {
            sequelize.import(`./${modelFile}`)
        }
    })
```

so I can't guarantee order. But shouldn't the `{constraints: false}` any cyclical dependencies?

If I remove either the `belongsTo` or the `hasOne`, then everything works fine (sort of). If I have just the `belongsTo`, then I can't do a query like:

```
        return db.models.Conversation.findAll({
            where: {
                status: {
                    $notIn: ['ready', 'error']
                }
            },
            include: [{
                model: db.models.Audio
            }]
        })
```

It complains that `Audio` is not associated to `Conversation`. Ideally, I want them both to be related to each other.

I am using v4, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example:

```
const Player = this.sequelize.define('player', {/* attributes */});
const Team  = this.sequelize.define('team', {/* attributes */});

Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

In your case:

```
const Audio = require("./audio");
Conversation.hasOne(Audio, { constraints: false });
```

```
const Conversation = require("./conversation");
Audio.belongsTo(Conversation);
```

Comment: That’s essentially what I’m doing and it’s causing the error mentioned above. Except I’m not doing reauire

Comment: @Shamoon please try `require`. Circular dependencies are generally resolved by Node.js

Comment: I am new to sequelize and facing the same problem. In my case I am already using require to add the models. using sequelize version 6.
I am using searate file for each model. So I have a require Model B inside model A file and also a require Model A inside model B file